# How to indent part of code in rubymine and keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ruby, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

I am trying to indent part of my code in `Rubymine editor`.

Is there a way how to do this fast using `keyboard shortcuts`?

**Update**

Example

Let say I have a file with 200 lines. With `keyboard shortcut` and `keyboard` ( w/o mouse selection ) I want to select e.g. lines `10 to 20` and this lines indent with `tab` or outdent with `shift-tab`.

Comment: You can select text using `Ctrl`+`W` (`Cmd`+`W` on Mac, or see the shortcut for **Expand Selection** action in your keymap, press several times to expand), or hold `Shift` while moving the caret with arrow, PgUp/PgDown keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Navigate to the first line
- Hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>
- Navigate to the last line
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> as appropriate

Comment: It appears to be setting default indentation. What if I want to indent by two characters instead of four?